# ReportViewer cannot shown in Firefox8 and Chrome15

Tags: reportviewer

I have an asp.net mvc3 project, it has some reports in aspx web pages. Everything works great in 2-3 weeks ago, but now, when I open the reports pages in FireFox8 and Chrome 15, the reports can not be displayed correctly.

In FF8, report content can be shown, but looks like css doesn't loaded, and report head control look like this:

[image]

In Chrome15, report head looks fine but content isn't shown up. I can see it has correct contents when using Firebug to view those .

Since data can ben loaded to browser, I think it maybe a browser compatibility problem, am I right?

Does anyone seeing same issues? I'm open to any suggestions.

BTW:My report viewer's version is 10.0.0.0.

Thanks.

[Edit in 12/21/2011]
**FireFox**
After several research on this, I have noticed when browse in firefox, server will catch an **[Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandlerInputException: Missing URL parameter: Name]**, and the **query string** is **OpType=BackImage&Version=10.0.40219.329&Color=%23ECE9D8&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.toolbar_bk.png**; **path_info** is **Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd**

This may be the reason why firefox can't show page with correct CSS.

I don't know why this happens in Firefox & Chrome, while in IE everything is fine.

I've found this link shows same excpetion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsreportcontrols/thread/80ce3ee8-e65b-476c-b668-ecc8e83ea73d

But I'm not sure how did he solve this, can you or somebody else gives some tip or example code to solve this?

**Chrome**
When browse in chrome, I found the report data is loaded into DOM, and surronded by a  with id="ReportViewer1_fixedTable". Inside that  element, there's a div with id="ReportViewer1_ctl09" nested in , if I remove the "height: 100%", the report can be seen.

this link http://www.apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php, explained why this 100% cannot be rendered correctly, but I'm still failed when trying to give a fixed height via CSS, the code can't be pasted here, please see [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1748832.aspx) as a reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, it's the "height=100%" problem.

Once I add following jQuery code, the report area can ben shown.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#ReportViewer1_ctl09").css("height", "auto");
    });
```

In FireFox, the report page raise an error as following:

"Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandlerInputException 缺少 URL 参数: Name"

and the Query String is: "OpType=BackImage&Version=10.0.40219.329&Color=%23ECE9D8&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Icons.toolbar_bk.png"

according to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vsreportcontrols/thread/80ce3ee8-e65b-476c-b668-ecc8e83ea73d) article, I think it's caused by a proxy that handles http request..

I checked my request, there's a "FiftyOne ..." in "Brwoser" property of "Request" ojbect.

Since fifty one is no longer used in this project, I removed it from Bin and web config, then the report can be shown in FireFox!

Hope this article can be usefule to other guys.